# Is this the correct understanding of tight coupling and loose coupling

Tags: coupling, definition

Coupling mean "dependency". It is the case of "Class A" dependent on "Class B" to get the job done.

Tight Coupling is when "Class A" Use the implementation of "Class B".
Loose Coupling is when "Class A" Use the abstraction on "Class B".

Is this the correct understanding or is it oversimplify ?

Comment: [This answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/160267/121080) also explains it pretty well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tight Coupling is when "Class A" directly calls "Class B" or an object of "Class B" to done a job. in loose coupling "Class A" calls  an abstract class or an object of an abstract class to done a job; so if "Class B" implements mentioned abstract then "Class A" indirectly called the "Class B" without depending on "class B"

as an example think "Class B" is Data layer that provide you services to run queries on SQLServer Db. what will happen if you want to run same application with for example an Oracle DB or MySQL or XML etc. If "Class A" instead of depending on "Class B" just depent on an abstract class like IDBProvider. then you can use "Class A" with any Class that just Implement IDBProvider. this is loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
// Let's say this method lives in a class MyClass
public void doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    foo.prepareProcessing();
    Worker work = foo.createWorker();
    work.dispatchTask(new Task(bar), 12);
    work.start();
    foo.waitForWorker(work);
    foo.finishProcessing();
}
```

Contrast it to the following:

```
public void doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    foo.runTaskAtPriority(bar, 12);
}
```

In the first example, classes `Foo` and `MyClass` are tightly coupled: `MyClass` not only depends on `Foo`, but also on `Foo`'s dependencies, like the `Worker` and `Task` classes. Furthermore, `MyClass` depends on very specific internals of `Foo`: It has to call several methods in a certain order. It's much more likely that changing something in `Foo` will also require changing `MyClass`.

The second example only depends on `Foo` itself. So if `Foo` stops using a `Worker` internally, `MyClass` doesn't have to care. `MyClass` and `Foo` are loosely coupled.

In the end, it's all about knowledge: The more you need to know about a certain class/method in order to use it, the tighter the coupling.

"Depending on abstractions instead of concretions" is a common way to achieve low coupling. But introducing abstract classes/interfaces doesn't automatically reduce coupling - you rather need to think about ways to reduce the possible interactions (knowledge) one class has with another one.